# Unexpected result of logical AND operation between two uint64_t numbers

Tags: c++, uint64

In the following code, I check if the result of the logical AND operation equals zero:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

  uint64_t num1 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
  uint64_t num2 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
  uint64_t result = num1 & num2;

  if(result == 0) {
    std::cout << "It got here!\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output is: It got here!

However, if I don't use the "result" variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {

  uint64_t num1 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
  uint64_t num2 = 0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

  if(num1 & num2 == 0) {
    std::cout << "It got here!\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't print anything. Why does this happen?

Comment: Check the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for `==` and `&`.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. The operator == comes first

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator. So your if statement is equivalent to

```
num1 & (num2 == 0)
```

Since `num2 == 0` is true this works out to `0 & 1` which is 0.

Most compilers will warn in this situation if you have warnings enabled.